# 405 POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page sveltekit

Tags: typescript, forms, svelte, sveltekit

I have a this form in my `+page.svelte` at `route/manager` :

```
<form 
id="file_selection" 
action="?/manageFile" 
method="post"
use:enhance={() => {
    waiting = true;

    return async ({update, result}) => {
        await update();

        console.log(result);
    }
}}>
    <h1>
        Veuillez choisir ou déposer votre <span id="stressed"
            >relevé bancaire</span
        >.
    </h1>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" bind:files /> -->
    <label for="file">
        {message}
    </label>
    <p>Types de fichier accepté: <i>.xlsx</i> ; <i>.csv</i></p>
    <button class="cta" type="submit">Continuer</button>
</form>
```

and this is my `+page.server.ts` at the same path as my page :

```
import type { Actions } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const actions: Actions = {
    manageFile: async ({ request }) => {
        console.log(await request.formData());
    }
}
```

It is very simple and i've checked everything multiple times that it is right. But I still get the `405 POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page` error.

I've also tried without use:enhance too.

Any help is welcome, it is driving me crazy :/

Comment: Any chance this is a pre-rendered route or you are using adapter-static?

Comment: Try `method="POST"` (capital letters)

Comment: Capital letters didn't change anything. And for my adapter here's my code : ```import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto'; kit: { adapter: adapter() }```

Comment: I tried copying this code into StackBlitz, looks like it worked fine - does anything look different?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-zcunfs?file=svelte.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys sorry for all I've found my mistake and it was the dumbest one.

I forgot a `+` I my `+page.server.ts`

Sorry for that, will definitely check twice my files name in the future lol